# How to add/reference user specific data on/for each node?

Tags: nodes, users

I have a content type for which there is a user reference field,I can select multiple users for every node.
For each node I want to save some extra information for each selected user.
Like another dependent select field,which has multiple colors.

For example,
for node "X", user 1 and user 2 are selected.For user 1 I want to select color red,black.For user 2 I want to select color pink,green.

All the color data with user and node reference can be saved on the same node,or maybe somewhere else, How do I do that?

Any suggestions and help will be appreciated,Thanks.

Comment: There are 2 ways generally: 1. Custom compound field type (preferable), 2. the Field Collection module. Just be aware Field Collection has a lot of overhead and isn't the nicest to work with programatically. Use a custom compound field if you can

Comment: Hey ,thanks for quick reply.I haven't really used computed field but I don't want to calculate field also it may become difficult to get the data later. I just want to add data for each user,like in the drop down list and to be able to fetch later.Maybe I am not able to understand what you want to say,could you please give more info?

Comment: As Clive said, you can use Field Collection module for that. A field collection is represented as an entity that, later, you can use in views to get the data. I don't know about custom compound field type, but field collection can do the job really nice.